# mysqli display data based on row ID value

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I need to display an text in an row, based on an value from other table, I will explain... step by step to be all very CLEAR.

The table called "links" have an row called "title_id"

This row "title_id" from "links", have THE SAME value in other table called "titles" in the row named "id".

The table "titles" have another row called "title" - and tis is wath i need to display in this way...

a href= ..../>TABLE links row title_id = to TABLE titles row id -> DISPLAY HERE table titles row title (based on row title_id from the table links) < /a...

I hope you can understand, the result must be (a href=...>TEXT MOVIE TITLE< /a>)

Here is the base code, wath I need to change (I have commented the part wath need changes):

```
    <?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";
    $dbname = "dbname";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $sql = "SELECT id, label, title_id, season, episode, approved FROM links WHERE approved = 1 order by id desc LIMIT 30 OFFSET 1";
    $result = $last_id = $conn->query($sql);


    if ($result->num_rows > 0)
     {
        echo "<table><tr><th>ID</th><th>Audio</th><th>URL</th><th>Temporada</th><th>Episodio</th><th>Aprobado</th></tr>";
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<tr><td>".$row["id"]."</td><td>".$row["label"]."</td>";
            echo "<td>";
            if (empty($row['episode'])) {
         echo "<a href=";
         echo '/peliculas-online/'.$row["title_id"];
         echo ">HERE MUST HAVE THE VALUE FROM TABLE titles -> row title - based on $row["title_id"] </a>";
// -------------------------
        }
        else {
        echo "<a href=";
         echo '/series-online/'.$row['title_id'].'/seasons/'.$row['season'].'/episodes/'.$row["episode"];
         echo ">HERE MUST HAVE THE VALUE FROM TABLE titles -> row title - based on $row["title_id"] </a>";
// -----------------------------------
            }
            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row["season"]."</td><td>".$row["episode"]."</td><td>".$row["approved"]."</td></tr>";


        }
        echo "</table>";
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
    $conn->close();
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to modify your query a little to get this info.  You can join titles on those ids like so:

```
SELECT l.id, l.label, l.title_id, t.title, l.season, l.episode, l.approved 
FROM links l
JOIN titles t
ON l.title_id = t.id
WHERE approved = 1 
ORDER by id DESC
LIMIT 30 OFFSET 1
```

Then you can call your variables much in the same way you were doing before;  the same query will have `row['title']`

Learn more about [MySQL Joins](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

To get this in your script, just replace this row:

```
echo ">HERE MUST HAVE THE VALUE FROM TABLE titles -> row title - based on $row["title_id"] </a>";
```

with this:

```
echo '>'.$row['title'].'</a>';
```